# How do I tell which image was used to boot a juju machine?

Tags: juju, vmware

I have a couple of machines deployed in a vsphere cluster.  How do I tell which images were used to start the instances and from where they were downloaded?

I tried `juju status` and `juju show-machine 0`, and I don't see the data listed in either location.  Also, I can't find it in the /var/log/juju/* files on the controller node.

```
Machine  State    DNS            Inst id        Series  AZ  Message
0        started  10.245.201.51  juju-2c3f26-0  xenial      poweredOn
```